# Getting the selected value on autocomplete in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added an Autocomplete feature to a form on a HTML template, i would like to perform some actions when an hint is selected, is there any way to do it? I'm using [Jquery-Typeahead](https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/). Here is my actual code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Defining the local dataset
  $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi', function(data) {
    console.log(data)

    var dt = data

    $(() => {

      $('#myform').typeahead({
        source: {
          data: dt.results.map(record => record.item)
        },
        callback: {
          onInit: function($el) {
            console.log(`Typeahead initiated on: ${$el.prop('tagName')}#${$el.attr('id')}`);
          },
          onClick: function() {
            console.log(); //How can i console.log() the selected value here, for example?
          }
        }
      });

    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining an `onClickAfter` callback, it's called right after user clicks on an item. Something like this:

```js
onClickAfter: function(node, a, item, event) {
  // item will be the item you selected
  console.log(item);
}
```

You can also define the `onClickBefore` callback the same way, and it will be called immediately before "normal" typeahead behaviour kicks in

Comment: Indeed, it is the right way to go. Thank you a lot Marko!